# How to filter multiple dimensions with AND operator in Google analytics api v4?

Tags: google-analytics

Library: `"google/apiclient": "^2.2"` 
Framework: `Laravel 5.5`

I have a working filter. But only this actually work. It fetches all `ga:source` with `(direct)` value.

```
$dimensionFilter = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DimensionFilter();
$dimensionFilter->setDimensionName('ga:source');
$dimensionFilter->setOperator('EXACT');
$dimensionFilter->setExpressions(['(direct)']);

$dimensionFilters[] = $dimensionFilter;
```

Now, when I tried to do multiple filters like using `AND`

```
$dimensionFilter = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DimensionFilter();
$dimensionFilter->setDimensionName('ga:source');
$dimensionFilter->setOperator('EXACT');
$dimensionFilter->setExpressions(['(direct)']);
$dimensionFilters[] = $dimensionFilter

$dimensionFilter = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DimensionFilter();
$dimensionFilter->setDimensionName('ga:date');
$dimensionFilter->setOperator('EXACT');
$dimensionFilter->setExpressions(['20180413']);
$dimensionFilters[] = $dimensionFilter;
```

It only retrieves all with `(direct)` and also with `20180413`. It should only retrieve 1 result or 2 result having both `(direct)` and `20180413`.

Comment: The `v4` port to PHP is just a monstrosity... Having to create object instances and having to write several lines of codes to declare a simple filter. `v3` was much better in that sense. Had a quick look around, and couldn't find answer sorry.